# How to handle complex authorization in an ASP.NET MVC 4 / EF application?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-4, authorization

The ability to add, update, and delete various entities in my application is often determined by the relationships defined between the various users involved.  Here is an example:

1. A basic user or his supervisor can create tasks associated to the user, but only his supervisor can lock down the task so that the basic user will not longer be able to add/update/delete it.  Until locked down, both individuals will be able to update the task.

What is the best approach to implement these kind of complex and advanced rules that deal with the relationship of users and the state of the entities (new, existing), as well as other things like maybe a user-defined status associated to the entity?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> What is the best approach to implement these kind of complex and advanced rules that deal with the relationship of users and the state of the entities (new, existing), as well as other things like maybe a user-defined status associated to the entity?

You want to use an authorization standard, namely XACML, the eXtensible Access Control Markup Language. XACML is:

- a standard developed by OASIS, just like SAML is
- a standard that focuses on fine-grained access control: access control that takes into account user information, resource information, state, and contextual information
- a standard that implements the attribute-based access control (ABAC) model: the user information, resource data, and state can all be seen as attributes
- a standard that uses policies and rules to structure the attributes and grant / deny access: XACML is policy-based
- a standard that can be applied across multiple layers e.g. across the presntation tier, the data tier, the business tier of an MVC application
- a standard that can be applied to multiple technologies and languages e.g. C# (MVC4 and more), Java, Python...

With XACML, you can easily implement relationships e.g.: *an employee can approve a transaction if and only if the transaction amount < employee approval limit AND the transaction is not locked*.

Where to go from here?

- Check out NIST's page on [ABAC](http://csrc.nist.gov/projects/abac/).
- Check out OASIS XACML's [page](https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/tc_home.php?wg_abbrev=xacml) and spec
- Check out existing implementations (open-source and vendor such as the one I work for, [Axiomatics](http://www.axiomatics.com).)

Answer (score 0):

At a bank I worked for, we had a loan management system that allowed the entire bank hierarchy to see loans in their reporting structure.  For instance, a Market exec could see the loan portfolio of all of his/her reports at once.  Additionally, s/he had the ability to select from a list of all reports' (direct or indirect) names to view the portfolio of that employee.

It was complex, but we had to maintain an HR database of the reporting structure.  Once we had that, we built user functions (could be done as stored procs, too, but user functions worked well in our LINQ to SQL backend) that allowed us to check whether user x supervises user y.

So, in your example, as long as you know who owns the task, and have access to a method that can be used to determine if the task owner reports to the currently-logged-in user, you should be able to easily enable/disable the "lock" button on the page.

The legwork lies in creating that reporting structure DB, **and keeping it up to date!**